# Use AWS CDK to create CodeBuild Project for building Docker Images

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I want to define a CodeBuild project in source code using the AWS CDK.  The CodeBuild project needs to be able to build and then push docker images.

When creating a new CodeBuild Project in the AWS Console there's an option:

> **Privileged**  Enable this flag if you want to build Docker images or want your builds to get elevated privileges.

[image]

I don't see an equivalent api for turning on the **Privileged** flag in the [API Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.Project.html).

```cs
var codeBuildProject = new Project(this, "Example_Build", new ProjectProps
{
    ProjectName = "ExampleBuildFromCDK",
    // How to add Privileged?
    BuildSpec = BuildSpec.FromSourceFilename("example/buildspec.yml"),
    Source = Source.CodeCommit(new CodeCommitSourceProps
    {
        Repository = Repository.FromRepositoryArn(this, "CodeCommit", CodeRepositoryArn),
        BranchOrRef = "refs/heads/example/added-docker-images"
    })
});
```

And if I try to run my build without setting **Privileged** to true, I'll get the standard error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

**How to I use the AWS CDK to create a CodeBuild Project that has "Privileged" to build Docker images?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
    new Project(this, "coolBuildProject", {
      // ... setting up your codeBuildProject
      environment: {
        // this is the essential piece you're looking for
        privileged: true,
      },
    });
```

In general, you can find all other (build) environment settings here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.BuildEnvironment.html#privileged

Comment: That's the one!  Setting was hidden in the `Environment` property https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.BuildEnvironment.html#privileged

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the previously accepted answer was written for CDK 1.x.  For CDK 2.x, I found that the default build image does provide support for building docker images.  This is easily remedied by explicitly setting the build image as follows.

```
new Project(this, "coolBuildProject", {
      // ... setting up your codeBuildProject
      environment: {
        // this is the essential piece you're looking for
        privileged: true,
        // insert your preferred image below.
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.fromCodeBuildImageId("aws/codebuild/standard:6.0"),
      },
    });
```